# reactStringReplace: trouble formatting bold/italic/underline text with capture group regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Shared question from: https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace/issues/33

react-string-replace: https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace

I'm having trouble using `reactStringReplace` to format text with bold/italic tags. I have it set up as follows:

```
var text1 = "[b]Testing bold [i]and italic[/i] tags[/b]"
var text2 = "[b]Testing bold [i]and italic tags[/b][/i]"

let replaced = reactStringReplace(text1, /\[b\]([\s\S]+)\[\/b\]/g, (match, i) => {
   return <b key={i}>{match}</b>
})
replaced = reactStringReplace(replaced, /\[i\]([\s\S]+)\[\/i\]/g, (match, i) => {
   return <i key={i}>{match}</i>
})

// result (html)
<b>Testing [i]bold and italic[/i] tags</b>
<b>Testing [i]bold and italic tags</b>[/i]
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with `reactStringReplace`, with the regex I'm using, or something else. If I apply the italic replace first, I get italic tags where I'd expect them to be, but the [b] tags remain unchanged. Is this use case possible using `reactStringReplace` or do I need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`?

Bonus: is `reactStringReplace` capable of handling unbalanced tags, or improperly formatted tags as in `text2` or should I be doing some pre-processing to ensure the strings are properly balanced and formatted?

Comment: As of now, it's not possible to handle nested replacements. I saw you are working on a patch to add this feature to reactStringReplace. But that's arguably outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample has multiple issues,

- you do not use the recommended JSX key format `<i key={match + i}>{match}</i>` (see below)
- your matches overlap
- your greedy `+` quantifier may match too much.
- missing `;`s, etc.

Ad. 1: Quoting from the full [example](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace/blob/master/example/index.js):

> In many React examples you will see the `i` or `index` variable used
>   as the key for JSX tags (such as the `<a>` tags in this example), however in this case we are iterating in three separate loops.
>   This means that we cannot use `key={i}` because all three JSX
>   tags could get the same key.

Ad. 2: The most crucial part here, however, is your **matches are overlapping**, and this does not go well with `reactStringReplace`.

A demonstration:

```
const text = 'Hey @ian_sinn#reactconf';
let replacedText;

// Match @-mentions
replacedText = reactStringReplace(text, /@(\w+)/g, (match, i) => (
  <b key={match + i}>@{match}</b>
));

// Match hashtags
replacedText = reactStringReplace(replacedText, /#(\w+)/g, (match, i) => (
  <a key={match + i} href={`https://twitter.com/hashtag/${match}`}>#{match}</a>
));
```

We have distinct matches in this sample: first, `@ian_sinn` is matched and replaced, then `#reactconf`, thus the replacement works as intended; however, if you change the first regex replacing `\w` with a `.` you get an overlapping match: Now, the second replacement will not be applied.

It works if you avoid overlapping matches:

```
render() {    
    const text = '[b]Testing bold [i]and italic[/i] tags[/b]';
    let replacedText;

    replacedText = reactStringReplace(text, /\[b\]((?:(?!\[\/b\]|\[i\]|\[\/i\]).)*)/g, (match, i) => (
      <b key={match + i}>{match}</b> 
    ));

    replacedText = reactStringReplace(replacedText, /\[i\]((?:(?!\[\/b\]|\[i\]|\[\/i\]).)*)/g, (match, i) => (
      <b><i key={match + i}>{match}</i></b>
    ));

    replacedText = reactStringReplace(replacedText, /\[\/i\]((?:(?!\[\/b\]|\[i\]|\[\/i\]).)*)/g, (match, i) => (
      <b key={match + i}>{match}</b>
    ));

    replacedText = reactStringReplace(replacedText, /\[\/b\]((?:(?!\[\/b\]|\[i\]|\[\/i\]|$).)*)$/g, (match, i) => (
      <b key={match + i}>{match}</b>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        {replacedText}
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

But this requires you to throw more sophisticated regex at the problem, gives you ugly markup, and arguably, defeats the purpose of the whole adventure...

Ad. 3: Compare this with a simple vanilla regex replace using an ungreedy match: `[\s\S]+?`

```js
const str = `[b]Testing bold [i]and italic[/i] tags[/b]`;
const result = str.replace(/\[b\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/b\]/gm, `<b>$1</b>`)
                  .replace(/\[i\]([\s\S]+?)\[\/i\]/gm, `<i>$1</i>`);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

---

Verdict: Sad, but now [official](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace/issues/33#issuecomment-392118886). As of now, reactStringReplace does not handle nested replacements:

> since replacements can change the data type to something other than
>   strings. If you look here you'll see that it only runs replacements on
>   strings. Once your first replacement has been run the element in the
>   result array will be an object (i.e. `<b>...</b>)` so no replacements
>   will be run on the inner string.